# Zoom out lags on Xamarin.Form implementation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to zoom in/out an image in a Xamarin.Form App.
My problem is that when I made the pinch gesture to zooming out the image it starts to lag and flashing all over the display. Instead the zoom in works perfectly.
I had already follow the official guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pinch) and any sort of forum/comunity but I wasn't able to reach a working answer.
Could anyone help me?
I copy/paste here the section of the code. I localize the bug where I try to set the currentScale variable.

NOTE: I have other methods into the class but they don't manage images or related properties so I don't copy/paste them.

```
    public partial class ResizeFoto : ContentPage
        {

        double currentScale = 1;
        double startScale = 1;       
        double minScale = 0;
        double maxScale = 2.5;

        private void PinchGestureRecognizer_PinchUpdated(object sender,PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e){
                    switch (e.Status)
                    {
                        case GestureStatus.Started:
                            startScale = imgUserFoto.Scale;
                            break;

                        case GestureStatus.Running:

                            // LAS test 4
                            //Input gesture:
                            //Definition: "The distance between the user's digits, divided by the 
                            //last reported distance between the user's digits in the pinch gesture"
                            // --> ZOOM IN = e.Scale > 1
                            // --> ZOOM OUT = e.Scale < 1

                            //ZOOM IN --> works good
                            if (e.Scale > 1)
                            {
                                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                                currentScale = Math.Min(currentScale, maxScale);
                                imgUserFoto.Scale = currentScale;
                            }

                            //ZOOM OUT --> not working, bug
                            else if (e.Scale < 1)
                            {
        //HERE MAYBE THE BUG
                                    currentScale = minScale + (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
       //also tried: currentScale = (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                                    currentScale = Math.Max(minScale, currentScale); 
                                    imgUserFoto.Scale = currentScale;
                                }
                            }
                         break; 
                        case GestureStatus.Completed:

                         break;
                     }
        }

}
```

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions relating to the Visual Studio application, not code you create with it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had to do something similar and I almost searched the whole earth and found nothing then I came up with this:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;

 public class ZoomImage : CachedImage
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
    private double StartScale, LastScale;
    private double StartX, StartY;

    public ZoomImage()
    {
        var pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);

        var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
            this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
        else
        {
            AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
            this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
                StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                AnchorX = Clamp(1 - (StartX + e.TotalX) / Width, 0, 1);
                AnchorY = Clamp(1 - (StartY + e.TotalY) / Height, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                StartScale = Scale;
                AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
                AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                if (e.Scale < 0 || Math.Abs(LastScale - e.Scale) > (LastScale * 1.3) - LastScale)
                { return; }
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                var current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
                Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                break;
        }
    }

    private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T: IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
            return minimum;
        else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
            return maximum;
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

What this does:

**Pinch zoom, Pan and Swipe movements together with double tap centre zoom and un-zoom**

Note: I have used FFimageLoading's `CachedImage` because I needed to cache the data in case you do not intend this replace `CachedImage` with `Xamarin.Forms.Image`

Comment: hi @G.hakim, first of all thanks for the unswer!! :)
I tried to apply the pinchgesture section of your code inside my situation but unfortunately it doesn't work. There're still those annoing flashing bugging effect during the gesture running. D:

Here you can find the only one discussion similar to ours, that I was able to find in the web: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554053/xamarin-zoomin-lags-on-android (saddenly neither that solution is not usefull for me)

Comment: I would suggest you use the control and not the pinch code only as that would help

Comment: what do you mean with "use the control"? :)

Comment: Use the zoom image control in place of whatever you are using right now and see if that works or not because the issue you are facing could be something wrong with the code you have and hence could be causing the issue

Comment: Thanks, do you have some Xamarin guide link or something else where I can study this functionality?

Comment: The link that you have added covers everything

Comment: Ok, must be my fault but I can't find nothing usefull in those link *shameface*

Comment: Yes you won't find anything its not well documented it took me 2 weeks to do what i have done i would suggest you give it a shot as the issue you are talking about is not happening with me so maybe it works

Comment: The problem is that your code won't fit my situation completely, I need to extract the pinchgesture section, or, at least, find some alternative code that works. :S *troubles everywhere*

Comment: adding more notes: I see that you use double tap to zoom out and re-centre the image. This works also in my case and I've already used that "patch" before asking here into this forum. The problem is that my boss requires the zoom out using pinch gesture (two fingers gesture, to be clear) so I should reach that, I don't think that double tap patch will be ok for him. 
However thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you upload your full code so i can understand better?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to zoom in and out the image. The effect should be something like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veP7Q47CcQ4 .
I have the perfect worked zoom in but the zoom out is bugged with some lag flashing effects. That's all.
In a theoretical way the zoom out should work exactly as the zoom in, but in practice is not like that.

Comment: The control that i have added should provide you with this kind of ability and i have this working in two of my Applications did you actually try using my solution?

Comment: Yes I copy/paste (and adaptate to my case of course) al this section of your code:

private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    { [...] }

but it doesn't resolve my bug unfortunally, i still have that annoyng flshing effect instead of smoothly movement

Comment: I am asking you to use my image control, not just the code!! Using the code and not that would literally not work for sure

Comment: My image is inside a relative layout inside a stack layout (for many reasons). I tried to use all your image control but it moves the layout insted of the image :S
For that reason I decided to try just with the pinchgesture code.

The last thing that i can try is to rebuild all the page of the app but that means to re-do 1 month of work just for a bugged zoom out and I don't think that my boss will be happy

Comment: furthermore in my class I have already implemented many API calls, pangesture and other functionality so I can't replace all with your image control. I'm praying to find just a fix for the pinchgesture section.
If I'm right your code realize the zoom-out with double tap? you just use the pinch for zoom-in right?

Comment: The pinch literally works for zoom in and zoom out! I wish i had a device and i could show you the video

Comment: I totally agree with you, in fact I'm totally disappointed because in my code zoom in works great instead - with the SAME code- zoom out is bugged :(
This code will drive me crazy

Comment: I decided to implement your code in a NEW app, completely clear. I still see the flashing bugged effect during the zooming-out gesture, so the fault is not "some strange collateral effect" due to my code. 
So sad :(

Comment: I have this same code in two other applications and there is no " flashing bugged effect" while zoom out so maybe I need to test properly

Comment: Hey @G.hakim your control is the business, and is amazing on iOS.  Unfortunately, on Android, I also get a weird zoom out jitter bug. I'll take a video and put it, uh, somewhere.

Comment: Video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09fCyBT62BE&feature=youtu.be.  Trying to zoom out at the end on the image has nil effect.

Comment: The final issue with zooming out, the OnPinchUpdated recognizer doesnt even fire... weird issue

Comment: In that case contact xamarin